# i want to select the rows which does not follow where condition or "except where condition"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two table.
fisrt is "tab_task"

```
   task_id|   task_name  | created_by | status
   -------------------------------------------
     1    |    task1     |    aarav   | 1
     2    |    task2     |    rahul   | 0
     3    |    task3     |    aarav   | 0
     4    |    task4     |    jasmin  | 0
     5    |    task5     |    yamini  | 1
     6    |    task6     |   priyanka | 0
     7    |    task7     |    manish  | 1
     8    |    task8     |    aarav   | 1
```

and the second table is "tab_user"

```
   user_id| txt_full_name|
   -------------------------
     1    |    aarav     | 
     2    |    rahul     |  
     3    |   yamini     |   
     4    |   jasmin     |    
     5    |   manish     |   
     6    |  priyanka    |
```

`SELECT created_by from tab_task where status='1'`
now we have 4 rows "aarav, yamini, manish and aarav".

Now I want to fetch the "txt_full_name" from "tab_user" where "txt_full_name" is not equal to "tab_task's created_by".
I mean i want to fetch : rahul, jasmin, priyanka from "tab_user".

Comment: Roughly: Select x.* from x left join y on y.something = x.something and y.otherthing = ? WHERE y.primary_key IS NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution:

```
SELECT txt_full_name FROM tab_user
    WHERE txt_full_name NOT IN (SELECT created_by from tab_task where status='1')
```

(note that the above assumes the `created_by` column is `NOT NULL`, otherwise the query won't return any rows since comparison with `NULL` yields `UNKNOWN` - [fiddle - doesn't work with NULL data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b01/1)).

Comment: What happens if a created_by which is NULL is returned from the sub-query?

Comment: That's why I usually do `NOT EXISTS` instead. Less surprising result if a NULL value suddenly shows up.

Comment: And also, `NOT EXISTS` will have better performance than `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides @Jiri Tousek's `IN` solution, also you can use `JOIN`, `EXISTS` syntax:

```
select u.txt_full_name
from tab_user u
left join tab_task t
on u.txt_full_name = t.created_by
and t.status = '1'
where t.created_by is null;
```

Or

```
select u.txt_full_name
from tab_user u
where not exists(
     select 1 from tab_task t where u.txt_full_name = t.created_by and t.status = '1'
);
```

and see [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da909/2) here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the tables, then select the null rows:

```
SELECT txt_full_name FROM tab_user
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT created_by from tab_task where status='1'
)tbStat
ON created_by = txt_full_name
WHERE created_by IS NULL
```